Movie about a guy who goes to a toy dimension
I'm trying to remember a movie that I must have seen on cable when I was 3 or 4 years old. It would have been the late 90s. I'm not certain of this, but it might have aired on Disney channel.
The movie is live action and involves a guy who somehow gets transported to what I think is a dimension populated by sentient life size toys. He befriends either a raggedy ann doll or possibly a rip off of her. I believe there is a scene where he upsets her and to express her sadness she paints tears on her cheeks because she can't actually she'd tears.
If anyone knows the title of this movie, I would greatly appreciate it if you would share. 

Sounds like the Josh Kirby (who appears frequently in ID questions) chapter Trapped on Toyworld. Josh Kirby... Time Warrior! was a film series from the mid-90s about a boy travelling different worlds. In this chapter, he's transported into a toy world and meets Annie, who's pretty much Raggedy Ann, and at some point she draws tears on her face. Here's Annie:

And here's the Josh Kirby trailer:



